# How to allow a function argument to dynamically only be one value from a typescript interface?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am creating a theme handling function.

The function that has a `desiredColor` parameter. I want passed in argument *to only be* one of the keys from the interface provided as the type for the underlying colors.

Is there a way to restrict the `desiredColor` to only be **one** of the key values of the underlying interface?

(is there a way to do this without also having to maintain an adjacent enum?)

```js
const handleThemeColors = (mode: ThemeMode): any => {
  const colorsHandler = (desiredColor: Array<keyof PaletteColors>) =>
  // goal ^ desiredColor can be either: blueDark, blueMain, or blueLight
 {
    switch (mode) {
      case 'light':
        return colorsLight[desiredColor];
      default:
        return colorsDark;
    }
  };
 ...
}
```

```js
interface PaletteColors {
  blueDark: string;
  blueMain: string;
  blueLight: string;
}

const colorsLight: PaletteColors = {
  blueDark: 'rgba(2, 189, 185,1)',
  blueMain: 'rgba(0, 203, 198,1)',
  blueLight: 'rgba(147, 231, 229,1)'
}
```

Comment: _is there a way to do this without also having to maintain an adjacent enum_ Seems like `PaletteColors` should be an enum.

Comment: Why an `Array`?

Comment: Was in the process of trying to work with it, thought maybe getting around to having the keys was in the right direction

Comment: Why not just `desiredColor: keyof PaletteColors`?

Comment: That works, thank you so much. It has been a minute since I've been in JS/TS land and I knew there was something basic I wasn't thinking of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely, it's as simple as

```
const colorsHandler = (desiredColor: keyof PaletteColors) =>
```